# Sending HTML Template via email django

Tags: django, django-email

Sorry I just have a question on a previously answered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005080/how-to-send-html-email-with-django-with-dynamic-content-in-it) but couldn't comment cause my reputation isn't high enough. :P

For this answer where should I place my html that I'd like to send via email, that they called "mail_template.html"?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template should be in the templates directory .

eg:- 
 All the templates can be stored in a folder in the root directory.
Now if the template is in templates folder in the which you have to mention in `settings.py` then you can simply write the name of the hmtl template and it should work.
or else if the template is in a sub-folder then you have to write  `subfolder/template.html`.