# Django sending emails with link

Tags: python, django, email

I have an email verification while registering, and the verify link must in the form of a hyperlink.

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings

def send_email_verification_mail(email, first_name, verify_link, exp):
    html = """
    <a href="{link}">Click to verify</a>
    """
    html.format(link=verify_link)
    subject = 'Your accounts need to be verified'
    message = f'Hi {first_name.capitalize()},\n\nClick on the link to verify your 
    account \n 
    \n{html}\n \nThis link will expire in {exp}'
    email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    recipient_list = [email]
    send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
    return True
```

[This is the what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kx0e.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send html email with django with dynamic content in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005080/how-to-send-html-email-with-django-with-dynamic-content-in-it)

Answer (score 0):

[str.format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method returns the formatted string, it doesn't modify the original string. Try assigning the return value to your original string.

```
html = html.format(link=verify_link)
```

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/email/#send-mail) says that `send_mail` has `html_message` argument and,

> If html_message is provided, the resulting email will be a multipart/alternative email with message as the text/plain content type and html_message as the text/html content type

So you can do as it is shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49894619/7052505) answer to modify your code:

Comment: Now the formatting works properly, but it appears as an entire tag. it is required as a hyper link.

Comment: Can you check the edited version of my answer?